2017 Community Moderator Election Results
Quantitative Finance's first moderator election has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:
   
Since this is the same group as current pro tempore moderators, you won't notice much of a change. However, please join me in thanking all of the beta moderators for their time and commitment!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here, or view a summary report online.

Congratulations to ALL the candidates ! and of course to the new moderators :)

Congratulations! great effort and great work.

Congratulations, thank you all for your implication and keep up the good work :)

Congrats, I really liked @madilyn comments about improving readers experience. Grouping questions and working on a better tag classification would be great

Congrats to olaker, SKRX and Bob Jansen for being elected. You guys deserved it. Also props to lehalle, if there were 4 slots, I'd have felt he was deeply qualified for the role.
Thanks to everyone who voted for me and our campaign pledge. You are the ones whom this community needs the most, and I hope you can invest the same trust and support in our re-elected moderators.

Thanks. By the way you can still help us by contributing to the site so please don't go away because as we said in the election discussions: WE NEED YOU! :-)

@SRKX Geez, of course I'll still be here.

Thank you, @madilyn. It was a tight race! I hope you would consider  nomination in the next election.
